# got stuck - uploading via Curl an data-binary option

Tags: php, curl, post, file-upload

first i've to say, that i'm totally new to cURL. But I've just code some lines with curl and PHP to Upload some XML files.
The following Code is working very good. (just looked around and build up a simple working solution)

Now i've got the issue to use the curl --Data-Binary option instead of the -F (Form) option.

The following Code is in the php-File (curlupload.php):

```
<?php

@$authcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST["acode"]);

if ($authcode == "1234"){
echo "AuthCode ok\n";

$upstatus = "1";
$uploadpath = "files/";
$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$target_file = $uploadpath . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

#echo "Acode:" . $authcode . "\n";
#echo "filedata= ".$filedata."\n";
echo "target_file= ".$target_file."\n";
#echo "1 upstatus= ".$upstatus."\n";

if (strpos($target_file, ".xml") == true) {
    $upstatus = "1";
    echo "2 upstatus= ".$upstatus."\n";

    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.\n";
        $upstatus = "0";
    }

    #echo "4 upstatus= ".$upstatus."\n";
    if ($upstatus == "1") { 
        if ($filedata != '')
        copy($filedata,$target_file);
        echo "\n-----\n";
        echo "success\n";
    }

}else{
    $upstatus = "0";
    #echo "3 upstatus= ".$upstatus."\n";
    echo "Filenamecheck Failed.\n";
}



if ($upstatus == "0") {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.\n";
} 
 }else{
  echo "NO.";
}
?>
```

my cURL command for uploading a file is the following:

```
curl -v -F 'file=@/root/testfile01.xml' -F 'acode=1234' http://webserver/upload2/curlupload.php
```

Now i'm going to use the -d and --data-binary option like this:

```
curl --data-binary "file=@testfile02.xml" --data "acode=1234" http://webserver/upload2/curluploadtest.php
```

with the 2nd above command i receive the following messages:

```
AuthCode ok
target_file= files/
Filenamecheck Failed.
Sorry, your file was not uploaded.
```

so, the variables got no input - Can somebody please tell me, what i've got to change in the PHP file, so, that the databinary option used by curl is going to work?

Thanks a lot for your helping toughts!